# showing data in modal in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, materialize

I'm using Laravel and I'm trying to delete or update the services on my platform
I'm  using confirmation modal for that..
but when I delete or or update or show content in the modal it always works on the first row only...

that's the code

```
@foreach ($services as $service)
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col l4">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <span>
                            <a class="btn-floating btn-large modal-trigger tooltipped waves-effect waves-light red hoverable" 
                               data-position="left" 
                               data-tooltip="Supprimer ce service"
                               data-text-color="grey-text"
                               href="#modal1">
                                <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                            </a>
                        </span>

                        <span>  
                            <a class="btn-floating btn-large modal-trigger tooltipped waves-effect waves-light green" 
                               data-position="right" 
                               data-tooltip="Modifier ce service" 
                               data-delay="20" 
                               href="#modal2">
                                <i class="material-icons" href="#modal2">update</i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="modal1" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s6">
                                <p>Voulez vous vraiment supprimer ce service ?</p> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="col s6">
                                <form action="/Services/{{$service->id}}" method="POST">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    @method('DELETE')

                                    <span>   
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn purple hoverable waves effect" value="supprimer">
                                    </span>

                                    <span>    
                                        <a href="#" class="btn red hoverable waves effect modal-action modal-close" id="non"> Non</a>
                                    </span>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is it show first record only after delete or update action?

Comment: Is it show first record only after delete or update action?

Comment: Is it show first record only after delete or update action?

Comment: yes
for example when I want to show the title of the service , I get only the first item's title for all the rest of the services...

Comment: Define modal popup for each record if you in loop if you dont want to use jquery that get and service id and pass into modal form. I've answered, please check and let me know if work for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Invoke modal via jquery like

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

In Loop Anchor

```
    <span>  
                                <a class="btn-floating btn-large modal-trigger tooltipped waves-effect waves-light green modalclick" 
                                   data-position="right" 
                                   data-tooltip="Modifier ce service" 
                                   data-delay="20" 
                                   data-id="<?php echo $service->id; ?>"
                                   href="javascript:void(0)"

>
                                    <i class="material-icons" href="#modal2>update</i>
                                </a>
                            </span>



$(".modalclick").click(function(){
   var current_id = $(this).attr("data-id");

   //use jquery below to change modal form action with id
$('#myModal').modal('show');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define modal popup for each record if you in loop if you dont want to use jquery that get and service id and pass into modal form.

```
<?php $a = 1; ?>
@foreach ($services as $service)
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col l4">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                         <span>  <a class="btn-floating btn-large modal-trigger tooltipped waves-effect waves-light red hoverable" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Supprimer ce service" data-text-color="grey-text" href="#modal{{$a}}"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></span>
                         <span>  <a  class="btn-floating btn-large modal-trigger tooltipped waves-effect waves-light green" data-position="right" data-tooltip="Modifier ce service"  data-delay="20" href="#modal2"><i class="material-icons" href="#modal2">update</i></a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="modal{{$a}}" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s6">
                                <p>Voulez vous vraiment supprimer ce service ?</p> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="col s6">
                                <form action="/Services/{{$service->id}}" method="POST">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    @method('DELETE')
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn purple hoverable waves effect" value="supprimer">
                                    </span>
                                    <span>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn red hoverable waves effect modal-action modal-close" id="non"> Non</a>
                                    </span>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <?php $a++; ?>
@endforeach
```

See if it is work for you.